# A bank's unprofessional treatment of POA

Tags: banking

My aunt assigned me as her Financial Power of Attorney. I mailed the POA document to her bank, and after that, bank employees were treating me like I was her POA, for example, giving me the balance on the account. Later, I needed a direct deposit authorization, and the bank president said he needed to consult with the bank's attorney. His response was, since the POA document states that my aunt does not authorize me to make gifts to myself or to anyone else, they would have to monitor her account all of the time to make sure that doesn’t happen, so the lawyer advised against having me as POA on her account, since the bank cannot monitor her account all of the time.

Does that sound right? They already were treating me as if I was already her POA. She lives outside of the United States, and mailing a revised POA document to her would take weeks, because the mail service there is poor. In addition, the lawyer and witness would have to be hired again to come to her house.

Comment: what about changing banks?

Comment: Actually, the bank President said that the attorney suggested opening a new account in her name, at a different bank, and have the money from the original account wired into the new account. The original bank doesn't have any reviews online, so if I left a bad review, their entire rating would be one star.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is. Were you *denied* the DD authorization? If you have POA, you have POA; it's not something, IIUC, that the bank can authorize or reject. Also, is the direct deposit so that you can *add* money to the aunt's account? If so, I don't know why the bank is worried about unauthorized *withdrawals*.

Comment: @chepner: I sent POA document to bank, & when I called for her balance, they acted like I was POA. Then, I asked them to process the online access request I submitted & the direct deposit authorization. The bank prez said he'd have to consult with the attorney, & attorney advised bank to not allow me to be POA. For the DD, they're willing to call her to get approval, & then send me the signed form, so I can attach it to the paperwork for disbursement from her investment account. But, after the deposit, money would have to be transferred to a foreign bank account, so I would need online access.

Comment: Again, I'm not sure POA is something the *bank* grants. If your aunt grants you POA, you have access to your aunt's accounts as if you were your aunt. If you *don't* have POA, the bank has likely already violated something by giving you account balances. The only thing I can think of is the bank is challenging the *validity* of the paperwork you are providing, and so isn't *recognizing* your POA.

Comment: I agree with the bank, your POA has conditions that are too difficult to monitor. Why should they assume liability for your convenience?

Comment: @Mattman944: Because they already told me I was her POA after they received the POA document from me.

Answer (score 4):

In your question, you note that your aunt has granted you a limited power of attorney over her accounts, with the proviso that you cannot draw money out to pay anyone.

If your aunt’s intent is for you to just monitor her accounts, consider getting her to grant you *non-value* or *view-only* access to the relevant bank accounts. I’m no lawyer, but it seems that’s roughly what your POA amounts to, hence your freedom to access balance information but not to authorise outbound direct deposits.

On the other hand, if your aunt’s intent is for you to transact on her accounts, she will have to lift the proviso that stops you from withdrawing money from her accounts. Obviously, if you aren’t allowed to withdraw money from her accounts, the bank shouldn’t let you do so.

From what you’ve written, it looks like the bank is doing the right thing here by the account holder (your aunt).

Comment: Perhaps there's a difference between "do not make gifts" (per the question) and "do not pay anyone" (the interpretation in your answer).  For example, a transaction treated differently under these two interpretations would be a payment to the government of tax the aunt owes on some investment property.  Then the restriction may be pretty clear legally, but impossible for the bank's automated system to enforce.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks for highlighting that distinction. It would explain the banker’s comment about having to monitor all transactions, which would effectively turn internet banking into staff-assisted banking.